# DXA 2.0 displays weird Link resolving behaviour

Tags: dxa, dynamic-linking, dxa-2.0

We have a DXA 2.0 (Java) implementation with Link List entities on the home page which have a list of component links linking through to article pages. All works well if the article detail page is published, dynamic linking ensuring that link URL is maintained in the manner you would expect from Tridion.

However, when the article page is unpublished, the link remains in the link list on the home page, but resolves to the home page itself. This should not happen as the article component is no longer actually on any published page.

I am pretty sure this didn´t happen in DXA 1.x so it seems like a bug, as dynamic linking no longer functions correctly. Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Issue made on github: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/issues/21

Comment: Might be related to caching. Does the link eventually disappear?

Comment: No - the link remains. But I don't see how it could be related to caching - the article isn't on the homepage, so dynamic linking should never give the result that it is

Comment: Is that article DCP component also unpublished in CME?

Comment: Its not configured to publish as a DCP at all